# Can anyone advise on how to apply custom ordering of a legend for pywaffle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, legend

I understand that pywaffle accepts parameters of `matplotlib.pyplot.legend` in a *dict*. I'm not really across how to apply these parameters to generate a legend with a custom order of categories.

Can anyone please advise how to update my code to apply a customer order to my legend?

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7, 7]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=10,
    values=df['values'],
    title={'label': 'Latest data, 2022', 'loc': 'center'},
    labels=list(df.category),
    legend={'loc': 'lower center','bbox_to_anchor': (.5, -0.1),'ncol': len(df)},
    starting_location='SE',
    block_arranging_style='snake',
    icons='person', icon_size=32, 
)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend is created in the order that the values and corresponding labels are given.  Once created, you can create it again with a different ordering of the items.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle

values = [12, 20, 15]
labels = ['twelve', 'twenty', 'fifteen']
legend_dict = {'loc': 'upper center', 'bbox_to_anchor': (.5, -0.01), 'ncol': 3}
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass=Waffle,
    rows=10,
    values=values,
    title={'label': 'Latest data, 2022', 'loc': 'center'},
    labels=labels,
    legend=legend_dict,
    starting_location='SE',
    block_arranging_style='snake',
    # icons='person', icon_size=2,
)
handles_dict = {h.get_label(): h for h in fig.axes[0].legend_.legendHandles}
new_label_order = ['fifteen', 'twelve', 'twenty']
new_handles = [handles_dict[lbl] for lbl in new_label_order]
plt.legend(handles=new_handles, **legend_dict)
plt.show()
```

[image: pywaffle with changed legend order]

Comment: This is really helpful thank you. Any ideas on how to order the squares the same way as the legend?

Comment: Spoke to soon. Managed to figure it out. Thanks again!